# Pandas combine and merge rows

Tags: python, pandas

My original data has some column data that I'm expanding to their own columns. Here's how it starts:

```
Order ID    Items    Order Line item Properties 1 Title    Order Line item Properties 1 Value
--------    -----    ----------------------------------    ----------------------------------
1           x        Org ID                                1234
2           x        Org ID                                5678
2           x        Ship From                             DEN
2           y        Ship To                               CLE
2           y        Org ID                                5678
2           y        Ship From                             DEN
2           y        Ship To                               CLE
```

I have some code that creates columns for `Org ID`, `Ship From`, and `Ship To`. The resulting data looks like this:

```
Order ID    Items    Org ID    Ship From    Ship To
--------    -----    ------    ---------    --------
1           x        1234      None         None
2           x        5678      None         None
2           x        5678      DEN          None
2           x        5678      None         CLE
2           y        5678      None         None
2           y        5678      DEN          None
2           y        5678      None         CLE
```

I'm trying to get the data to look like this:

```
Order ID    Items    Org ID    Ship From    Ship To
--------    -----    ------    ---------    --------
1           x        1234      None         None
2           x, y     5678      DEN          CLE
```

I think I have a grasp on everything except concatenating the items to show up as `x, y` when the rest of the data is the same.

Here is some of the code that gets me almost all of the way there:

```
df.groupby('Order ID').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

I can get to the string I want with this: `[str(x) for x in df['Items']]`, but I'm not sure how to get that into the items field for the resulting row(s).

What can I do to merge, concatenate, squash, join, or whatever the correct word is to end up with `x, y` for items on order 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
df.groupby(['Order ID','Org ID'])['Items'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str)))).reset_index()
```

Output

```
      Order ID  Org ID  Items
0         1     1234      x
1         2     5678    y,x
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track. How do I get this to also include the other columns? Ship From, Ship To, etc?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment question on Arun's answer, you can add more columns by adding the column titles in the groupby list:

```
df.groupby(['Order ID','Org ID', 'Ship To', 'Ship From'])['Items'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.astype(str)))).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have a lot of columns? Do I need to add them all? Or I guess I could do something like `[col for col in df.columns]`

Comment: You only need to add the columns that you need.   Or, you can do a pd.merge on the Order ID to join data sets if you need any other columns.